# Microsoft Graph API - Error in PUT driveItemVersion-id content API

Tags: upload, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to use the following Graph API endpoint in C#

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drive/items/{driveItem-id}/versions/{driveItemVersion-id}/content](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drive/items/%7BdriveItem-id%7D/versions/%7BdriveItemVersion-id%7D/content)

I can execute this API with GET method, but PUT method is returning an error.

GET:

```
await _graphServiceClient
    .Sites[siteId]
    .Drives[driveId]
    .Items[itemId]
    .Versions["1.0"]
    .Content
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

PUT:

```
await _graphServiceClient
    .Sites[siteId]
    .Drives[driveId]
    .Items[itemId]
    .Versions["1.0"]
    .Content
    .Request()
    .PutAsync<DriveItemVersion>(file);
```

Exception:

> Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: 'Code: itemNotFound Message: Item
> not found

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to update the content. In that case you need to call the following endpoint

```
PUT /sites/{site-id}/drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/content
```

C# code

```
await _graphServiceClient
    .Sites[siteId]
    .Drives[driveId]
    .Items[itemId]
    .Content
    .Request()
    .PutAsync<DriveItem>(fileStream);
```

It will create a new version. You can check the list of all versions

```
var versions = await _graphServiceClient
    .Sites[siteId]
    .Drives[driveId]
    .Items[itemId]
    .Versions
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```